# Jquery datepicker: activate by click on div. Input should be hidden

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using the jquery datepicker with option to have it be activated by a click on an icon.

http://jsfiddle.net/su6Hq/

```
<input type="hidden" id="datepicker"> 

$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
      showOn: "button", 
      buttonImage: "/static/calendar.gif",
      buttonImageOnly: true
    });

  });
```

That works fine, but I'd very much like to have the image be defined in the css, not in the js. ideally this would be a DIV with a background url, which I would define in the css.

The actual input needs to be hidden.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this 
HTML :

```
 <input type="hidden" id="datepicker">
 <div class="trigger">Click Me</div>
```

Javascript:

```
  $(function() {

    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({

   });

    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "yy-mm-dd");

    $(".trigger").click(function(){ $("#datepicker").datepicker("show"); }); 

     });
```

Comment: I tried something similar, but the datepicker cannot be invoked with a hidden input, unless you use the image icon option. I created an answer to get around this.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a div with background-image.You can not achieve this using Pure CSS. The icon is rendered as an image object which has source `src` property to image.